# WebSocket Ratchet в Yii2 - идентификация пользователя

Tags: yii2, сокет, websocket, ratchet

Использую в проекте сокеты. Проект написан на Yii2. Сокеты настраивал по этой инструкции - [Ratchet](http://satirics.net/wp/2015/09/22/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-websocket-%D0%B2-yii2/)

Все работает, только я не понял одного: как мне при подключении передать, например, email пользователя, и потом уже при поступлении сообщений отправлять ему сообщения? Может кто сталкивался, буду благодарен за помощь

Answer (score 0):

Можешь передавать сообщение при подключении, которое содержит id юзера и сохранять его вместе с ссылкой на коннект, а на сервере уже доставать почту по id и слать письма в последующем

P.S. Наверное, уже поздно, но все-таки )